Possible breaking changes upgrading a Ubuntu 20.04 version running PHP-FPM + Nginx
Our team has a production server running Ubuntu 20.04, and with its standard support ending next year, we are considering upgrading the version to either 22.04 or 24.04.
Would either of these versions cause breaking changes to the web server and process manager mentioned in title? Or anything to be careful about in general for that matter. Any advice about the overall process is also appreciated.
We are using nginx/1.24.0 and php8.1-fpm.
I've tried searching with relevant keywords, but has not found anything specific. Which itself could be a good sign, but I want to be sure.
